What is the fastest way of converting a &u8 into a u16 value in rust?
I'm making my way through https://rust-exercises.com/ and one of the exercises has you implement a Saturating16 type. Specifically, one of the tests requires the ability to construct a Saturating16 with a &u8.
Here is the implementation I've gone with:
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct SaturatingU16 {
    value: u16,
}


impl From<&u8> for SaturatingU16 {
    fn from(value: &u8) -> Self {
        SaturatingU16 {
            value: (*value).into(),
        }
    }
}


The bit I'm interested is this: value: (*value).into().
Here I'm assuming that dereferencing *value will implicitly copy the underlying &u8 into an u8, and then the .into() will create a new u16. Firstly, is this assumption correct?
Secondly, if correct, it seems that the dereference is overhead we don't need - we're creating two values and throwing one of them away immediately. Is there a way to go directly from &u8 to u16?

This is the kind of thing that compiler optimizations take care of and that you don’t really need to worry about, especially if you’re not making disassembly-informed decisions.

What you have is the fastest way.
A reference is a pointer type, so there has to be a dereference (a.k.a. a load) at some point to get the referenced value. That step is not "overhead".
The concern about retrieving the u8 and only then converting it to a u16 makes sense, but under optimization passes and how registers work in CPUs means the distinction between a u8 and a u16 largely melt away. Registers are always address width (or larger) so loading a u8 into a register automatically means it can be used as a u16 - assuming higher bits are cleared.
Generating the x86 assembly from &u8 to u16 yields this:
#[no_mangle]
pub fn convert(num: &u8) -> u16 {
    (*num).into()
}

convert:
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    retq

A single instruction was able to do this conversion (combination of byte load and zero-extend).
